# SWI Prolog use :-lib(ic)

Tags: swi-prolog

I am new to prolog and i am trying an example from web, but there is an error about the lib

```
:-lib(ic).

:-use_module(library(ic)).
```

The error is

*Goal (directive) failed: user:lib(ic)*

*source_sink `library(ic)' does not exist*

how to use this in prolog?
I am using SWI Prolog IDE.

Comment: use_module scans the library spec, what's supposed to be ic.pl?

Comment: lib(ic) seems to be an ECLiPSe library, may be clpfd in SWI-Prolog